# Popstate jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

На сайте ajax навигация:

```
var nav = {
 go: function(url) {
  ...
  $.get(url, function(data) {
   $('#page').html(data);
  });
  ...
 }
}

<a href="javascript://" onclick="nav.go('/test')">test</a>
```

Вот например на странице **/test** перед </body> размещаю:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
 alert(1);
});
```

И переходя на неё через nav.go(), а после, нажимаю кнопку "Назад", почему-то выскакивает 2 alert(1), хотя должен выскакивать 1.

Третий час не могу понять в чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема видимо в том что два раза загрузился бинд. Если вы после этого опять нажметё тест и назад и при этом будет 3 алерта то точно в этом дело

Comment: @Чад, да, Вы правы. Как быть?

Comment: > Вот например на странице /test перед </body> размещаю:

Зачем там body... зачем вы делаете bind в этом месте... 

у вас скрипт в содержании ответа от .get(). Возвращая ответ ajax, не печатайте заголовков футеров, скриптов и прочего. (google *isajax() php*)

Comment: и еще маленькая просьба - 

## никогда

не пишите

    onclick="nav.go('/test')"

###  особенно используя jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно наверное добавить не анонимный обработчик как то так:

```
...
var Handlers = {};
Handlers.popstate = null;
...
if(!Handlers.popstate)
{
  Handlers.popstate = function(){alert(1);}
  $(window).bind('popstate',Handlers.popstate);
}
...
```

Хотя, по идее должна быть проверка средствами jquery на наличие уже привязанного евента, но ща не помню её :-)

Comment: @Чад, не надо саппортить плохие архитектуры.

Comment: Ну, это ответ на вопрос. Человеку требуется решение, насколько я понимаю, сиеминутное, а не из разряда - вы пишете какашку, надо всё делать по другому. Я не телепат, чтобы из такого набора информации вникать что конкретно хочет вопрошающий, а, согласитесь, чтобы предложить хорошую архитектуру, надо знать нюансы. Реальность далека от учебников... И, где вы тут увидели архитектуру? Это всё равно что по вырытому котловану, говорить о красоте будущего здания...

Comment: архитектура такая - вместо разработки js и server-side отдельно, у него грузятся js из ajax  запросов, мне это понадобилось ровно один раз в жизни - когда мне захотелось поставить свой скрипт в проприетарный софт (для хука была доступно только jquery.js, в которой я и реализовал загрузку скриптов).

Comment: А чем js из ajax ставит крест на отдельной разработки js и server-side ?

Answer (score 4):

Зачем чудо-велосипед, когда есть [pathjs](http://mtrpcic.github.io/pathjs/), который ещё и строку url установит, и у которого есть откат на хештеги, если браузер не поддерживает pushState?

Comment: Зачем писать программы когда можно заказать у Нас например? :-)